# How to consistently get / calculate Gmail sending limits

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, quota

I'm trying to figure out a way to get how many more emails a gmail / gsuite account can still send in the next 24h. In short I would like to have a consistent way to get gmail sending quota.

From my understanding the gmail / gsuite quota for sending can be summarized with the following (excluding MailApp):

Using GmailApp in app script, [limits are](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas):

- 1500 recipients per day for **GSuite accounts**
- 100 to 500 recipients per day for GSuite accounts in **trial**
- 100 recipients per day **Gmail accounts**

Using "raw" Gmail Apis, the [limits are](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852):

- 2000 messages per day for **GSuite accounts**
- 500 messages per day for GSuite accounts in **trial**
- 500 recipients per day **Gmail accounts**

Considering that in my implementation in appscript I could use GmailApp or the [advanced gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail), how can I consistently get the remaining quota to showcase the user and eventually stop emails ?

I was following this two roads but with no results:

1) in appscript I can use [MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getremainingdailyquota)
However from my tests it looks like that this method doesn't return the real value, but just a "last time computed" value that is refreshed in long intervals (took 8h in my test)

this is the code I've used:

```
function logRemainingQuota(e) {
var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
Logger.log("Remaining email quota now: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
}
```

I tried to send emails via gmail and some addon via the same account and the quota never reduced immediately, just hours later.

2) calculate the value using gmail api [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)
By making the following call I can get the number of emails sent in the last 24h in the field resultSizeEstimate or by simply counting the messages.

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=from%3Ame%20newer_than%3A1d%20in%3Aanywhere&fields=resultSizeEstimate&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

the query is: `from:me newer_than:1d in:anywhere`
However this value doesn't seem to be true and is returning way more data.
Also, there's no way to distinguish between an gsuite account that is in trial and one that is not, which makes it difficult to apply the calculation in a reliable way.

Summing up, I've the following questions:

- is there a way that can be used to calculate / get the number of remaining quota for sending messages (or recipients) with gmail (much better if in app script) ?
- is there a way to understand if a gsuite account is in trial ?

Sorry for the long post and thank you for helping !

---- **EDIT** ----

So, I've updated my code to perform testing on my script:

```
function sendWithGmailApp(e) {

  var now = new Date();
  GmailApp.sendEmail("example@gmail.com", "current time", "The time is: " + now.toString());

  Logger.log("Gmail App used ");

  var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log("Remaining email quota now Gmail App: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
}

function sendWithGmailAPI(e) {
  var draft = GmailApp.getMessageById('17139fda2e54af59');
  var raw = draft.getRawContent();
  var message = Gmail.newMessage();
  Gmail.Users.Messages.send(message, "me", Utilities.newBlob(raw, "message/rfc822"));
  Logger.log("Gmail Api used ");

  var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log("Remaining email quota now Gmail Api: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
}

function showquota(){
var emailQuotaRemaining = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  Logger.log("Remaining email quota now Gmail App: " + emailQuotaRemaining);
}
```

I've also made a copy of the script in order to determinate if the quota is user based or user/script based.
Here is my conclusions:

- MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() works for emails sent via GmailApp
- quota is related to GmailApp / MailApp and is user based (so other scripts can consume the quota)
- using GmailApi (advanced service) will not consume this quota, so It falls back in the [standard gmail quota](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852).
- I've made my tests in the legacy GAE engine and it works

So now my question is,

1) is there a way I can predict the quota of a user via gmail API if my application uses the advanced service ?

2) using the advanced service, will also affect URLFetch quota since it is a wrapper basically ?

Comment: Try not to exceed sending faster that quota for 24 hours/seconds in 24 hours

Comment: What do you mean by "However this value doesn't seem to be true and is returning way more data"? About your second question the answer is no, there's no way you can programmatically know if a G Suite account is on trial. For me `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` it's working correctly giving the real quota value right after sending a message, could you share the code you're using to test this? Are you using [V8](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) version?

Comment: hi @AndresDuarte thank you for replying. I've added the code in the question, really simple function actually. I'm on V8 and with a gmail account. I'm my test I'm using gmail directly to send emails or an add-on that uses GmailApp, however the result changes only after hours have passed.

Comment: When you're manually [sending emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839) through Gmail UI you're not using Gmail API quota which is the one `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` method returns. About the Gmail Add on, i'm not being able to reproduce your problem, i'm using an add-on which sends a message and then logs the remaining daily quota and it's giving the expected result. I tested my Add-on in the [DEPRECATED_ES5] runtime version as Add-ons in the V8 are having problems as stated in this [public issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/149993404#comment10).

Comment: Hey @AndresDuarte thank you again, I've made more tests and added them in the question. As you said it seems that the quota is reduced consistently on ES5, probably the add-on I had was using the raw apis. Still do you know if there's any way I can calculate the gmail sending quota or if using the gmail advanced service will reduce the URLFetch quota ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getremainingdailyquota) will return the remaining quota related to the use of MailApp and GmailApp, whose limits are stated [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

When making a [messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) the response includes messages from hangouts as well, this ones come with the "CHAT" label. In any case, you could filter the sent messages by the "SENT" label.

You may try to find a workaround using the messages.list method, the problem is you don't know at what time the quota for each user is being refreshed, as stated [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852):

> Limits per day are applied over a rolling 24-hour period, not a set
>   time of day.

In case you're going to try to develop some kind of close workaround, the [Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties) class that can be used to store values for each user using the script and time-based [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)
, may be useful for you.

About your Advance Service question, their quotas are not specified in the documentation, but it makes sense to be limited by the URLFecthApp limits as both are treated as [external APIs](https://ctrlq.org/google.apps.script/docs/guides/services/advanced.html) requests. Also, be aware that Gmail API has its own set of [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota).

Comment: Thank you for you detailed explanation :) the "time of refresh" for gmail sent quota I think just takes into account the last 24h right ? Anyway maybe with all this information it should be possible to try something. Too bad there's no way to find out if a gsuite user is in "trial mode"