# Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail - Gmail Auto Archive

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, gmail, quota

Triggering code below every 15 minutes to archive labels fed from a google sheet and getting this error:

> Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail.
> at archiveThreadsByLabel(archiveOldMessagesByLabelAndCategory:52:24)
> at go(archiveOldMessagesByLabelAndCategory:21:15)

Any edit suggestions so I can run it every 15 minutes? Super new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Original source:
https://github.com/warwickallen/GMail-Archive-old-messages-by-label-and-category

Code:

```
function go() {
  var fname = "Archive old messages by label and category";
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fname);
  var spreadsheet;
  while ((typeof spreadsheet !== 'object') && files.hasNext())
  {
    try
    {
      spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(files.next().getId());
    }
    catch (e)
    {
      Logger.log("WARNING: " + e.message)
    }
  }
  if (typeof spreadsheet !== 'object')
  {
    Logger.log("FATAL: Cannot find a Google speadsheet called '" + fname + "'.");
    return -1;
  }
  var count = archiveThreadsByLabel(getSheetData(spreadsheet, "label"));
  count += archiveThreadsByCategory(getSheetData(spreadsheet, "category"));
  Logger.log("INFO: Archived " + count + " threads.");
}

function getSheetData(spreadsheet, sheet_name)
{
  var data_array = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet_name).getDataRange().getValues();
  data_array.shift();  // Remove the headings row.
  var data_object = new Object;
  data_array.forEach(function(datum) {data_object[datum[0]] = datum[1]});
  return data_object;
}

function archiveThreadsByLabel(minAgesInHours) {
  var blockSize = 50;
  var start = 0;
  var count = 0;

  while (1)
  {
    var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, blockSize);
    if (threads.length < 1) break;
    start += threads.length;

    for (var label in minAgesInHours)
    {
      var maxTime = new Date();
      var localCount = 0;
      maxTime.setTime(maxTime.getTime() - minAgesInHours[label]*3600000);
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
        if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate() < maxTime)
        {
          var labels = threads[i].getLabels();
          for (var j = 0; j < labels.length; j++)
            if (labels[j].getName() == label)
            {
              Logger.log("INFO:\n    " + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject() + "\n    " + threads[i].getLastMessageDate());
              threads[i].moveToArchive();
              localCount++;
              break;
            }
        }
      Logger.log("INFO: Archived " + localCount + " threads labelled '" + label + "' that are older than " + maxTime);
      count += localCount;
    }
    Utilities.sleep(1000);  // Google doesn't like it if GmailApp API calls are called too often in a short period of time.
  }
  return count;
}

function archiveThreadsByCategory(minAgesInHours) {
  var blockSize = 50;
  var count = 0;

  for (var category in minAgesInHours)
  {
    var start = 0;
    var localCount = 0;
    var maxTime = new Date();
    maxTime.setTime(maxTime.getTime() - minAgesInHours[category]*3600000);
    var query = 'in:inbox category:' + category + ' before:' + maxTime.getFullYear() + '-' + (maxTime.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + (maxTime.getDate() + 1);
    while (1)
    {
      var threads = GmailApp.search(query, start, blockSize);
      if (threads.length < 1) break;
      start += threads.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
        if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate() < maxTime)
        {
          Logger.log("\n    " + threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject() + "\n    " + threads[i].getLastMessageDate());
          threads[i].moveToArchive();
          localCount++;
        }
      Utilities.sleep(1000);  // Google doesn't like it if GmailApp API calls are called too often in a short period of time.
    }
    Logger.log("INFO: Archived " + localCount + " threads categorisaed as '" + category + "' that are older than " + maxTime);
    count += localCount;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We have [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) in apps script.

Your error means that you reached the quota of reading/writing emails in a day.

[image: quota]

20000 for consumer/free edition, 50000 for workspace accounts.

Easiest thing you can do is make the trigger interval longer that it won't go past the quota.

#### Note:

- The quota resets daily (as per name suggests) although I'm not sure what time exactly.
- Use `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` to check the remaining quota you have. You can check what methods does affect the quota by checking this everytime a method is executed in a test script. That way, you can estimate what your interval should be so you will not get past it.

Comment: At max it's only archiving 5-10 emails if it runs every 15 minutes. Forgive me if this is a stupid question but how could I possibly be hitting the 20,000 quota?

Comment: @AmandaM. it's not a stupid question at all. All the commands under `MailApp` and `GmailApp` that counts as read/write will increase your usage. I haven't found a documentation listing specific methods but `search` (read), `getLastMessageDate` (read), `getFirstMessageSubject` (read), and `moveToArchive` (write) does either read or write (in a sense) thus every execution of these methods increases your usage. A detailed testing was shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60934035/14606045). You might want to try using the advance services (Gmail API) as it is separate based on the linked post

Comment: Combine `MailApp`/`GmailApp` with `Gmail API` to reduce the strain on your quota. Also, take note that the quota is per user. If multiple scripts under the same user is using the `MailApp`/`GmailApp` methods, you need to consider all of them. The linked post above is very helpful and please try to check it out. Note that `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` seems to have delayed value being computed and returned. based on the testing above, it was said to be around 8h before updated. Confirmed it on my side as well that it isn't real time quota.